# Spring Batch Isolation Level

Tags: spring-batch, isolation-level

I have a Spring Batch job which is launched sequentially (next is launched when previous is finished) several times a day with different parameters.
Sometimes, I get an ORA-08177 error from the database.

To prevent this, I've set a customJobRepository as below :

```java
@Bean
    public Job createCamt(...
                          JobRepository customJobRepository) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                                .repository(customJobRepository)
                                ...
                                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository customJobRepository(
            @Qualifier("centralDataSource") DataSource centralDataSource,
            @Qualifier("centralTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager centralTransactionManager
    ) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(centralDataSource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(centralTransactionManager);
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

Looks like it doesn't work because I still have the ORA-08177 error from the database.
I looked in sql to see if I could open a transaction with `read commited` isolation level and it works :

```
SPRING_BATCH> set transaction isolation level read committed
[2020-10-05 10:35:43] completed in 3 ms
```

1. Why Spring Batch's isolation level isn't on `read committed` as it should be ?
2. How can this error even occur when each job is running **alone** ?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom `JobRepository` is not been taken into account, declaring it as a bean is not enough. If you want to use custom `JobRepository`, you need to provide a `BatchConfigurer`.

This is explained in the [Configuring a JobRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobRepository) section of the reference documentation.